# Error in Initializing a vector of structures with a size

Tags: c++, vector

I have a struct as defined below

```
struct valindex {
    int x;
    int y;
    valindex(int val, int index) : x(val), y(index) {}
};
```

I'm getting an error when trying to initialize a vector of this struct

```
vector<valindex> vals() // this works fine
vector<valindex> vals(20) // throws the error mentioned below when the size is specified
```

`required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = valindex*; _Size = long unsigned int; bool _TrivialValueType = false]'`

Can someone explain the cause of this error and provide a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Youre missing part of the error but more importantly the first version only "works" because it doesnt do what you think it does. Lookup Most Vexing Parse. The problem is your type doesnt have a default constructor and youre trying to create 20 default objects of that type.

Comment: Thanks . I missed adding the default constructor and couldn't figure that out from the error message.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<valindex> vals();
```

works because it declares a function named `vals` that takes no arguments and returns a `vector<valindex>`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse.

```
vector<valindex> vals(20);
```

does not work since it tries construct a `vector` of `valindex` and one of the requirements of creating such an object is that `valindex` be [default-constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible). Since  `valindex` is not default-constructible, that line cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector has another helpful constructor:

std::vector vals(999, {11, 55});

Vector vals will store 999 copies of valindex(11, 55). Welcome to c++11!

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site. Please read this [markdown tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format code in your answers.

Comment: Also, keep in mind the OP is asking for an explanation of the error as well as a solution, consider providing that too.